# How to install a functional ARM cross-GCC toolchain on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)

Tags: ubuntu, apt, gcc, arm, cross-compilation

## Context

I recently installed `Ubuntu 18.04, Linux foobar-VirtualBox 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 18:02:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` on a VM. I want to cross-compile applications for Cortex-M4F CPUs with **hard floating points**, and therefore I have installed the package `gcc-arm-none-eabi` version `15:6.3.1+svn253039-1build1` as well as  `libnewlib-arme-none-eabi` at version `2.4.0.20160527-3`.

## Problem

There is a linker error due to a conflict between my object files using hard floats and the libraries using soft floats. Some research indicates that this is a known [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) issue:

- [Debian issue](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=899264)
- [gcc ARM Embedded team issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+bug/1772332)

Note that I do provide the correct compiler and linker flags, and this project correctly builds with the Windows cross-toolchain from [GNU ARM Embedded](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded). I think it'd be pointless to paste the complete error here. If someone thinks it'd be required I'd be glad to edit this question.

## What I already tried

From my basic understanding, I have two solutions to get a functional GCC ARM toolchain:

1. Downgrade `gcc-arm-none-eabi` to return to a working version
2. Remove `gcc-arm-none-eabi` and install instead `gcc-arm-embedded` from the team GCC ARM embedded's PPA ([Install gcc-arm-embedded from the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~team-gcc-arm-embedded/+archive/ubuntu/ppa))

### Downgrading gcc-arm-none-eabi, but to what?

In order to downgrade `gcc-arm-none-eabi` I have to find a previous version in my package manager. I first updated the package list with `sudo apt update`, then I typed:

> sudo apt show gcc-arm-none-eabi
>
> Package: gcc-arm-none-eabi 
>   Version: 15:6.3.1+svn253039-1build1 
>   Priority: extra 
>   Section: universe/devel 
>   Origin: Ubuntu 
>   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers  
>   Original-Maintainer: Agustin Henze  
>   Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug 
>   Installed-Size: 307 MB 
>   Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), libgmp10, libisl15 (>= 0.15), libmpc3, libmpfr6 (>= 3.1.3), libstdc++6 (>= 5), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), binutils-arm-none-eabi 
>   Recommends: libnewlib-arm-none-eabi 
>   Homepage: http://gcc.gnu.org/ 
>   Download-Size: 24.3 MB 
>   APT-Sources: http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages 
>   Description: GCC cross compiler for ARM Cortex-A/R/M processors 
>    Bare metal compiler for embedded ARM chips using Cortex-M, Cortex-R and 
>    Cortex-A processors. 
>    This package is based on the GNU ARM toolchain provided by ARM.

There, I don't see any previous version. I think they should be listed here, but I don't see it. I can't downgrade if I can't provide the exact previous version I want to downgrade to.

### Using gcc-arm-embedded instead of gcc-arm-none-eabi

I followed the instructions given in the link above, which led me to these commands:

```
sudo apt remove gcc-arm-none-eabi
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:team-gcc-arm-embedded/ppa
sudo apt update
```

> [...] Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-gcc-arm-embedded/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
>   Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB] 
>   Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-gcc-arm-embedded/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release 
>     404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] 
>   Reading package lists... Done 
>   E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-gcc-arm-embedded/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file. 
>   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
>   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

```
sudo apt-install gcc-arm-embedded
```

> Reading package lists... Done 
>   Building dependency tree 
>   Reading state information... Done 
>   E: Unable to locate package gcc-arm-embedded

Basically it seems I have issues accessing the PPA. I tried the `apt` switch `--allow-unauthenticated`, but it didn't change the commands output.

## Question

Is there a way to make one of those two solutions work, or is there another way to get a functional GCC toolchain on Ubuntu 18.04 to build hard-float application for the Cortex-M4F CPU?

*(I've recently posted [a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51103706/arm-cross-compilation-vfp-registered-used-by-x-out-not-y-o-issue-on-linux-bu) on this issue, as at this time I thought it was a toolchain issue not so related with the Unix world. If I get an answer here I'll close it and redirect to this Q/A)*

Comment: This issue (newlib doesn't understand M4F should use hardfloat) in 19.04. It's a little disappointing that this hasn't been addressed correctly and we have to do an end-run around the official packages.

Answer (score 5):

You can download a functional toolchain from [developer.arm.com](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads) and install it manually after removing your existing gcc-arm-none-eabi package.

Go to that website, click the "Download" button and get:
`gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update-linux.tar.bz2`. Save it in your home directory.

Make sure you've uninstalled the old Ubuntu packages.

```
sudo apt remove binutils-arm-none-eabi gcc-arm-none-eabi libnewlib-arm-none-eabi
```

Untar the new package in your home directory:

```
tar -xjvf gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update-linux.tar.bz2
```

Add the new toolchain to your path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/(your user)/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update/bin/
```

At this point you should have a working ARM compiler and toolchain. (For the Unix newbies: if you close the terminal and open a new one, you'll have to re-run the `export PATH` statement so the compiler will get picked up again.)

To check if the compiler is installed:

```
gcc --version
```

Comment: After doing these steps, how can I quickly test that my ARM tool chain is working?